# BigQuery get the last inserted row

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool) but not found the way to get the last inserted row. What's the "standard" way to do it ?

Comment: What you are trying to solve? As bigquery doesn't have this notion?

Comment: For my unittests, Because I send b64 encoded gzip compressed data, on what I want to make the reverse operation (decode and decompress).

Comment: Are you adding records using Streaming API or import jobs?

Comment: A I do a test, if the table exists insert otherwise load (daily table) using bq command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to build a unit test to verify that your data round-trips correctly?

Here are two suggestions for you to consider:

1. Add an "identifier" column to your schema and use a
   client-generated unique id for each insert, then select the row
   where the identifier matches to find the data you just added.
2. Run your unit test pointing at a brand new empty table on each
   invocation, and then
   select all the data in the table. The data you just inserted will be
   the only data in the table, so you can verify that it decompresses
   back to your expected data. If you put a short TTL on the newly created
   table it will be automatically cleaned up for you, simplifying
   your test's data management.

Comment: It seems the only way to do, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if table exists by using [Meta-tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#meta-tables)
Querying this table you can also check when it was created, last updated, rows count, etc.

Comment: I don't see anything to get the last inserted row :(

Comment: Per your previous comment I understood that you are looking if table exists or not - my answer is about this. Note: there is no way to "get last inserted row"!

Answer (score -3):

SELECT MAX(column_id) FROM `yourdataset.table`

Where column ID is an auto-incremented primary key, this will find the row with the highest value and fetch that row ID